# Linking C library with a C++ dll: "unresolved external symbol __mingw_vsnprintf"

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cygwin, mingw

I've built a C++ Windows dll using Visual Studio - `a.dll`.

I used Cygwin and MinGW (`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`) to build a helper C library - `helper.lib`.

The dll needs to use the helper library, so  I modified Visual Studio project, tried to link with the library, but I get:

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __mingw_vsnprintf referenced in function inquiry` where `inquiry` is one of the functions inside `helper.lib`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're unlikely to succeed linking a static library from a different compiler into a dll, build the static library into a dll using mingw first

Comment: @AlanBirtles If I understood correctly: you mean `a.dll` should link with `helper.dll` instead of `helper.lib`?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Why are you mixing compilers? Your MinGW-built library is using MinGW standard library, which causes the MinGW error. You try to to build the MinGW library with static standard library to avoid this (linker flag `-static-libgcc` or (for C++) `-static-libstdc++`). You would still need to watch out not to call standard functions (e.g. `malloc()` and `free()`) across MinGW and MSVC code.