# Link MinGW built static library with a Windows DLL?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, gcc, mingw

I have a static `helper.a` library that I build using Cygwin and GCC toolchain. Now I need to build it for Windows.

I have a separate **Windows** dll `a.dll` which I did in Visual Studio, and this dll now needs to use the helper library.

How should I build the helper library for Windows, `helper.lib`?

If I build the helper library using [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/) in Cygwin, will I be able to link to it to `a.dll` from Visual Studio?

What's the right way to go in such "MSVC dll vs. MinGW lib" cases?

Comment: I believe you should be able to give the archive directly to the linker with no problems, given you use a C-interface because afaik the name mangling schemes with gcc and msvc are not compatible.

Comment: Mixing static libraries for different compilers is generally a bad idea if you can even get it to link. You can only really mix different compilers with dlls and even then you need to be careful. Wrap your static library into a dll or rebuild it in visual studio

Comment: @AlanBirtles It's a huge lib with all the build infrastructe already in place (targeting mostly linux and some DSP platforms, using GCC toolchain). Compiling it with MinGW works easily. The only question is how to get it to link with Windows DLL. To make things worse, Windows DLL is C++, while the lib is C.

Comment: Tried using mingw, but some [unresolved external symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65494567/linking-c-library-with-a-c-dll-unresolved-external-symbol-mingw-vsnprintf) problems already.

Comment: It's as @AlanBirtles said, if you need to mix libraries of different compilers, it can only be done with dlls. So why not do that?

Comment: If the static library is c then that makes it easier to create a dll from it

Comment: if you can get the `.def` file for the MSVC DLL, then you can use `dlltool` to create the `.dll.a` library file needed to link with the DLL (something like: `dlltool -D name.dll -d name.def -llibname.dll.a`).

Comment: @BrechtSanders I have all the sources, both for the dll and the helper lib.

Comment: @Danijel If you have all the sources it's best to avoid any mix of MSVC and MinGW, and just build everything with the same compiler.

Comment: @BrechtSanders I need to do a Windows [APO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/audio-processing-object-architecture) dll, so if I'm going to use the same compiler, it will be the MSVC...?